# how to remove or clustering default x labels using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

how to clustering o delete x values in my graph?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

[image]

Values are dates:

2020-08-02
2020-08-09
2020-08-16
2020-08-23
2020-08-30
2020-09-06
2020-09-13
2020-09-20
2020-09-27
2020-10-04
2020-10-11
2020-10-18

Comment: Plotting the ticks in the label is not a good idea. You can set the xticks directly. With dates I typically rotate the labels. Have a look at this: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

Comment: @user_na I have problem with # Round to nearest years.
datemin = np.datetime64(data['date'][0], 'Y')
datemax = np.datetime64(data['date'][-1], 'Y') + np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax) with your solution